# ldapsearch not accepting password with -w

Tags: linux, passwords, ldap

I'm trying to use the ldapsearch command to query an LDAP server. I can authenticate correctly when I use the -W option, which prompts for the password that I paste in. However when I use the -w option (to avoid keeping on pasting the password), it fails.

So the command that works is:

> ldapsearch -x -h ldap.myorg -D myusername -W -b DC=com,DC=myorg "(sAMAccountName=userlookingfor)"

But it doesn't work when I do:

> ldapsearch -x -h ldap.myorg -D myusername -w mypassword -b DC=com,DC=myorg "(sAMAccountName=userlookingfor)"

I get the error:

> ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
>     additional info: 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C09042F, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580

The password does contain special characters, however I've tried putting the password in quotes which didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

If you use bash, did you try to put the password in single quotes like the following? :

```
-w 'p@$sW0rD'
```

Or you can use the form $'string' to express special characters.
If your password is ***pass\word***, you can do like the following:

```
-w pass$'\\'word
```

or

```
-w pass$'\x5c'word
```

Comment: Thanks Ryo, the issue was needing to escape characters and the $'string' technique worked for me in bash.